# How to get transformed dataframe by grouping by one column and matching on another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like the following

```
col_a            col_b     col_c
2021-05-01        1           30
2021-05-01        3           40
2021-05-01        2           60
2021-05-02        1           70
2021-05-02        2           10
2021-05-02        3           20
```

And I want to make it into the following dataframe (i.e. adding `n` new columns based on how many different types in the `col_b` column in the original dataframe, and then matching based on `col_a` to fill in values)

```
col_a                 type_1   type_2     type_3
2021-05-01                30      60        40   
2021-05-02                70      10        20
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pivot`:

```
df = df.pivot(*df).add_prefix('type_')
```

To further transform into required structure use:

```
df = df.pivot(*df).add_prefix('type_').rename_axis(None, axis= 1).reset_index()
```

`OUTPUT`:

```
        col_a  type_1  type_2  type_3
0  2021-05-01      30      60      40
1  2021-05-02      70      10      20
```

One more `set_index`/`unstack` option:

```
df = df.set_index(['col_a','col_b']).unstack().add_prefix('type_')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then [`.add_prefix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for the column names. Clean up the column axis name by [`.rename_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and finally [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), as follows:

```
df = (df.pivot(index='col_a', columns='col_b', values='col_c')
        .add_prefix('type_')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
     )
```

Result:

```
        col_a  type_1  type_2  type_3
0  2021-05-01      30      60      40
1  2021-05-02      70      10      20
```